# If $n = m^2 + 1$ and $x$ is a square modulo $n$, then how to show that $n - x$ is also a square modulo $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I see that if $x \equiv y^2 (\text{mod } n)$, then $n - x \equiv m^2 - y^2 + 1 \equiv (m+y)(m-y) + 1 (\text{mod } n)$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I'm a complete beginner at number theory and would appreciate a small bit of assistance.

Comment: SuperHint: Write $x= kn + y^2$ and notice $m^2 \equiv -1$ modulo $n$

Comment: @Luis: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to see it is this: the equality $ n-1=m^2$ tells you that, modulo $ n $, $-1$ is a square, say $-1\equiv z^2$. So
$$
n-x\equiv -x=-y^2\equiv z^2y^2=(zy)^2.
$$

Comment: I see - thank you - I understand now.